# Process is not starting on Windows but on Linux

Tags: python, serial-port, multiprocessing

I have a problem with multiprocessing. I try to run a small Python script which works just fine on Linux but when I try to run it on Windows I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/Timo/PycharmProjects/csar/test/usb_test_proc.py", line 27, in <module>
    usb.start()  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 111, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 248, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 166, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup _thread.lock failed
```

Here is the code:

```
class Usbtg(Process):  
def __init__(self, port, ctrl=Controller()):  
    Process.__init__(self)  
    self.usb_port = port  
    self.ctrl = ctrl  


def run(self):
    self.ctrl.usb_ports.append(self.usb_port)
    ser = Serial(self.usb_port, 115200)
    while True:
        dsl = ser.readline()
        self.ctrl.get_dataset_queue().put(['USBDS', dsl])


ctrl = Controller()

usb = Usbtg(7, ctrl)  
usb.daemon = True  
usb.start()  
while True:  
    if not ctrl.dataset_queue.empty():
        print(ctrl.dataset_queue.get())
```

Comment: You should read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960296/trouble-using-a-lock-with-multiprocessing-pool-pickling-error