# Python sharing a lock between processes

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing, share

I am attempting to use a partial function so that pool.map() can target a function that has more than one parameter (in this case a Lock() object).

Here is example code (taken from an answer to a previous question of mine):

```
from functools import partial

def target(lock, iterable_item):
    for item in items:
        # Do cool stuff
        if (... some condition here ...):
            lock.acquire()
            # Write to stdout or logfile, etc.
            lock.release()

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    func = partial(target, l)
    pool.map(func, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

However when I run this code, I get the error:

```
Runtime Error: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance.
```

What am I missing here? How can I share the lock between my subprocesses?

Comment: There's another question about this same issue, though their particular error is different - [Trouble using a lock with multiprocessing.Pool: pickling error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960296/trouble-using-a-lock-with-multiprocessing-pool-pickling-error)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can't pass normal `multiprocessing.Lock` objects to `Pool` methods, because they can't be pickled. There are two ways to get around this. One is to create [`Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and pass a [`Manager.Lock()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Lock):

```
def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    l = m.Lock()
    func = partial(target, l)
    pool.map(func, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This is a little bit heavyweight, though; using a `Manager` requires spawning another process to host the `Manager` server. And all calls to `acquire`/`release` the lock have to be sent to that server via IPC.

The other option is to pass the regular `multiprocessing.Lock()` at Pool creation time, using the `initializer` kwarg. This will make your lock instance global in all the child workers:

```
def target(iterable_item):
    for item in items:
        # Do cool stuff
        if (... some condition here ...):
            lock.acquire()
            # Write to stdout or logfile, etc.
            lock.release()
def init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(l,))
    pool.map(target, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The second solution has the side-effect of no longer requiring `partial`.

Comment: Well thank you again, sir. This looks like exactly what I need. Really appreciate the continued help! Other options looked super involved. I will go with the initializer function to share the global Lock.

Comment: This worked great. I also put a `Queue` into the init to save passing that in each call.

Comment: @dano thanks a lot for your answer, I too had the same query and this one solves it perfectly, however I have another query that why is this approach not used frequently to share state between processes rather than doing so via a Manager object which has its own overhead of running a server processes and proxied access ?

Comment: @bawejakunal `multiprocessing.Lock` is a process-safe object, so you can pass it directly to child processes and safely use it across all of them. However, most mutable Python objects (like `list`, `dict`, most user-created classes) are *not* process safe, so passing them between processes leads to completely distinct copies of the objects being created in each process. In those cases, you need to use `multiprocessing.Manager`.

Comment: @dano thanks, so I have a `list of locks` and a `list of browser objects` that I need to share as global variables among processes, how would you suggest doing that ? I tried using `Manager` object but that gives an error about non-serializability of `thread.lock` while returning `Manager.Lock()` objects from the `list of locks`. Sample code here: https://codeshare.io/dnhhw

Comment: Could you explain why Lock needs to be created as global variable when using Pool, but can be passed as argument when using Process?

Comment: @neilxdims With a `Process`, the Lock is inherited by the child process as it is forked, and passed directly into whatever method you passed as the target of the Process.  With a `Pool`, when you pass arguments to methods like `map` and `apply`, the processes are already forked, so inheritance won't work. However the arguments to the `Pool`'s `initializer` function are inherited, so the `Lock` can be passed. But, for the methods the pool processes execute to have access to the `Lock`, it needs to be global; otherwise it will be inaccessible outside the `initializer` function.

Comment: Why can't you simply declare lock as global and access it from within each pool function?

Comment: @pistacchio On Linux platforms, you can do that. On Windows, you can't, because Windows doesn't support forking. You'll end up with a different lock object in each child process.

Comment: For anyone requiring related sample code for `joblib`'s `Parallel`, see this link: https://github.com/davidheryanto/etc/blob/master/python-recipes/parallel-joblib-counter.py

Comment: Should you pass the logger to your processes via Pool's initializer as well?

Comment: When using the second approach, it might be worth explicitly calling `multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')` to make it more explicit that sharing locks/barriers/etc without a Manager process is relying on 'nix systems defaulting to fork, especially as the macOS default start method changed in Python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Comment: Alternative option to force forking (or an error if it isn't available) that doesn't have a global side effect: `mp_ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')`. Then use the returned multiprocessing context to create the `Pool` and `Lock`/`Barrier` objects rather than the top level multiprocessing module methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version (using `Barrier` instead of `Lock`, but you get the idea) which would also work on Windows (where the missing `fork` is causing additional troubles):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def procs(uid_barrier):
    uid, barrier = uid_barrier
    print(uid, 'waiting')
    barrier.wait()
    print(uid, 'past barrier')    

def main():
    N_PROCS = 10
    with mp.Manager() as man:
        barrier = man.Barrier(N_PROCS)
        with mp.Pool(N_PROCS) as p:
            p.map(procs, ((uid, barrier) for uid in range(N_PROCS)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```