# NameError: name 'lock' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python program as follows

```
def send_request(data):
    global lock
    lock.acquire()
    print(data)
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_list = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

    pool.map(send_request, data_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Why did this error occur? `NameError: name 'lock' is not defined.`

#### updated

In the answer below, @Jean-François Fabre said that the reason is because “When running your subprocesses, python is "forking" and doesn't see the `lock` declaration, because it doesn't execute the `__main__` part in subprocesses.”
But in the following example, the subprocess should not see the `lock` definition too, but why is the program working fine?

```
import multiprocessing

def send_request(data):
   lock.acquire()
   print(data,' ',os.getpid())
   lock.release()

def init(l):
   global lock
   lock = l

if __name__ == '__main__':
   data_list = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
   lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8, initializer=init, initargs=(lock,))
   pool.map(send_request, data_list)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

Comment: See [Python sharing a lock between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25557686/222914)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of multiprocessing, you have to do more than that.

When running your subprocesses, python is "forking" and doesn't see the `lock` declaration, because it doesn't execute the `__main__` part in subprocesses.

Plus, on Windows (which doesn't have `fork`, the forking is emulated, leading to different behaviour compared to Unix-like platforms: in a nutshell, `fork` is able to resume the new process where the old process started, but on Windows, Python has to run a new process from the beginning and take control afterwards, this leads to side effects)

You have to create your lock as a global variable outside the `__main__` test (and you can drop `global` keyword, it will work without it)

```
import multiprocessing

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def send_request(data):
    lock.acquire()
    print(data)
    lock.release()
```

with those modifications your program prints

```
data1
data2
data3
```

as expected.