# Why doesn't multiprocessing Lock acquiring work?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, locking

Tried 2 code examples from first answer here: [Python sharing a lock between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557686/python-sharing-a-lock-between-processes). Result is the same.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from threading import Lock


def target(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        lock.acquire()
        time.sleep(1.1)
        print('hi')
        lock.release()
    elif arg == 2:
        while True:
            print('not locked')
            time.sleep(0.5)


def init(lock_: Lock):
    global lock
    lock = lock_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock_ = multiprocessing.Lock()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[lock_], processes=2) as pool:
        pool.map(target, [1, 2])
```

Why does this code prints:

```
not locked
not locked
not locked
hi
not locked
```

instead

```
hi
not locked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, call your worker processes "1" and "2". They both start. 2 prints "not locked", sleeps half a second, and loops around to print "not locked" again. But note that what 2 is printing has nothing do with whether `lock` *is* locked. Nothing in the code 2 executes even references `lock`, let alone synchronizes on `lock`. After another half second, 2 wakes up to print "not locked" for a third time, and goes to sleep again.

While that's going on, 1 starts, acquires the lock, sleeps for 1.1 seconds, and then prints "hi". It then releases the lock and ends. At the time 1 gets around to printing "hi", 2 has already printed "not locked" three times, and is about 0.1 seconds into its latest half-second sleep.

After "hi" is printed, 2 will continue printing "not locked" about twice per second forever more.

So the code appears to be doing what it was told to do.

What I can't guess, though, is how you expected to see "hi" first and then "not locked". That would require some kind of timing miracle, where 2 didn't start executing at all before 1 had been running for over 1.1 seconds. Not impossible, but extremely unlikely.

### Changes

Here's one way to get the output you want, although I'm making many guesses about your intent.

If you don't want 2 to start before 1 ends, then you have to *force* that. One way is to have 2 begin by acquiring `lock` at the start of what it does.  That also requires guaranteeing that `lock` *is* in the acquired state before any worker begins.

So acquire it before `map()` is called. Then there's no point left to having 1 acquire it at all - 1 can just start at once, and release it when it ends, so that 2 can proceed.

There are few changes to the code, but I'll paste all of it in here for convenience:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from threading import Lock

def target(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        time.sleep(1.1)
        print('hi')
        lock.release()
    elif arg == 2:
        lock.acquire()
        print('not locked')
        time.sleep(0.5)

def init(lock_: Lock):
    global lock
    lock = lock_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock_ = multiprocessing.Lock()
    lock_.acquire()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[lock_], processes=2) as pool:
        pool.map(target, [1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured out how lock works. I thought that when you call lock.acquire(), the rest of the threads are simply blocked.

Comment: Nope - not even close ;-) The only effect a successful `.acquire()` has is to cause all future attempts to `.acquire()` to block, until (if ever) `.release()` is called. If `.release()` is called, one outstanding (blocked) `.acquire()` attempt will succeed (if at least one such exists), but which one is not defined.