# multiprocessing.Pool map multiple arguments with shared value (Resolved)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, process-pool, shared-data

I am practicing on using shared values for multiprocessing.  I have an existing Process function that is working using shared value:

```
def run_procs_with_loop(lock):

    # this is my shared value 
    shared_number = Value('i', 0)

    print(__name__, 'shared_value in the beginning', shared_number.value)

    # create a process list to append each process spawned by the for- loop
    processes = []
    for _ in range(2):
        p = Process(target=add_100_locking, args=(shared_number, lock))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for _ in processes:
        p.join()

    print('shared_value at the end', shared_number.value)
```

The above process is directed to spawn TWO processes, and each process is directed to a function with args (shared_number, lock).  The function ran as expected.

I tried to convert it to a multiprocessing Pool - I attempted to pass the argument `[ shared_number, lock] *2 in my pool.map() statement (I want the Pool to spawn just two processes) but python is rejecting it:

```
def run_procs_with_pool(lock):

    shared_number = Value('i', 0)
    print(__name__, 'shared_value in the beginning', shared_number.value)

    # create processes using multiprocessing.Pool
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(add_100_with_lock, [(shared_number,lock)] * 2)

    print('shared_value at the end', shared_number.value)
```

Thanks for any helpful input in advance.

---

Update:

Someone suggested that I use starmap instead of map, but I am getting the error `RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`.  it looks like `multiprocessing.Pool` does not allow shared values to be passed in this way?

Thought I'd share the task function `add_100_with_lock` as shown below:

```
def add_100_with_lock(num,locking):
    for _ in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        with lock:
            num.value += 1
```

Is there way to make passing shared values work with multiprocessing.Pool to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```py
pool.map(add_100_with_lock, [(shared_number,lock)] * 2)
```

the iterable you are passing as a parameter is a `list` of `tuple`s, so `add_100_with_lock` will not get two parameters, but a single tuple, as if you called `add_100_with_lock((shared_number,lock,))` instead of `add_100_with_lock(shared_number,lock)`. `Pool.map` is implemented for functions having only one parameter.

You can change the definition of `add_100_with_lock`, although I do not recommend this solution. You can also wrap it into another function that receives a tuple and calls it, i.e.:

```
def wrap_add_100(args):
    return add_100_with_lock(*args)
...
pool.map(wrap_add_100, [(shared_number,lock)] * 2)
```

or use [Pool.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap), that expects a list of iterables and takes one of each for using as parameters:

```py
pool.starmap(add_100_with_lock, [[shared_number]*2, [lock]*2])
```

This last option is what I recommend, since it preserves the function signature.

Comment: Thank you azelcer.  However, when I tried starmap I got this error: "RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

Comment: It looks like process pool does not like passing shared data, when the multiprocess.Process allows it with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to resolve the restriction issue in multiprocessing Pool with regards to shared variables  by using Manager() object - per python documentation: `Managers provide a way to create data "which can be shared between different processes", including sharing over a network between processes running on different machines.`.

This is how I did it:

```
    # use the manager class to share objects between processes
    manager = Manager()
    shared_number = manager.Value('i', 0)
```

And since I would be passing only the shared_number (lock object is being passed at Pool creation time using the initializer= kwarg ( you can read all about it in the `multiprocessing lock()` discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557686/python-sharing-a-lock-between-processes)) , I can go back to using pool.map() instead of pool.starmap().

Here is the COMPLETE working module:

```
from  multiprocessing import Lock, Pool, Manager
import time

# init function passed to Pool initializer to share multiprocessing.Lock() object to worker processes
def init_lock(l, ):
    global lock
    lock = l

def add_100_with_lock(num):

    # Since our pool process spawns TWO worker processes, and both processes share the 'num' variable, 
    # this 'num' value will be 200 after our two processes are done executing (100 * 2 parallel processes = 200).
    # I applied multiprocess locking here to avoid race conditions between worker processes
    for _ in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        with lock:
            num.value += 1

# Pool method 
def run_procs_lock_with_pool():
    
    # use the manager class to share objects between processes
    manager = Manager()
    shared_number = manager.Value('i', 0)

    print(__name__, 'shared_value in the beginning', shared_number.value)

    # like shared values, locks cannot be shared in a Pool - instead, pass the 
    # multiprocessing.Lock() at Pool creation time, using the initializer=init_lock.
    # This will make your lock instance global in all the child workers.
    # The init_lock is defined as a function - see init_lock() at the top.
    pool = Pool(initializer=init_lock, initargs=(l,))
    # specified two worker processes in the pool with the arg "[shared_number]*2"
    pool.map(add_100_with_lock, [shared_number]*2)


    print('shared_value at the end', shared_number.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    run_procs_lock_with_pool()
```