# Python: acquire lock with and without multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I have a Python + Flask app at a Nginx + gunicorn server with multiple workers.

One of the key app components is an "index". Every worker and every thread shall have an unique index. At every operation the index is incremented by 1.

To prevent the same "index" to be used by more than one worker/thread, it is stored at Redis and the reading, incrementing and saving index to/from Redis is protected by a Lock().

Index is retrieved and incremented by non-threaded as well as multi-threaded functions.

The problem is that the Lock cannot be pickled by multi-threading.
I tried different arrangements of the two solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558333/14073103), but none worked, seems because has to work with both multi-threaded and non-threaded.

The code is (and must be) spread over 3 different .py files.

```
# rotator.py

from multiprocessing import Lock
lock = Lock()

def increment_index():
    time_before = datetime.datetime.now()
    with lock:
        index = retrieve_index_from_redis()
        index = index + 1
        save_index_at_redis(index)
        if index > 200:
            index = 0
            save_index_at_redis(index)


def rotator_of_index():
    new_index = increment_index()
    # do other stuff, log new index, etc
    return new_index
```

```
# salary_worker.py

from rotator import rotator_of_index

def do_work(n):
    index = rotator_of_index()
    # do other stuff
    return something
    
    

# do_work without multithreading:
def do_more_work():
    something = do_work(n)
    # do more stuff
```

```
do_with_threading.py

from salary_worker import do_work

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def do_work_with_threading():
    list_of_n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = ThreadPool(15)
    list_of_results = pool.map(do_work, list_of_n)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(list_of_results)
```

I tried also a [ray Pool](https://medium.com/@sibrahim1396/replace-python-multiprocessing-pool-with-ray-pool-due-to-oom-induced-deadlocks-dae897578a4) to replace the multiprocessing Pool, without success.

Any alternative to make it work?

Comment: The lock need to be constructed in your main thread and passed as an argument to do_work.  do_work() can then pass it as an argument to increment_index

Comment: You should be using the increment command on redis https://redis.io/commands/incr/ . The increment should not be done on the python side, but rather the redis side. Once you do this, you won't need the lock.

Comment: @arrmansa That is a possible solution, but there is a missing detail in my code (I edited the question to include it). If index > 200, then index must be set zero and saved to redis to work as a kind of carrousel.

Comment: in that case you could use a custom lua script or just use index modulo 200. I don't think you'll be incrementing more than 2^63-1 times so modulo should be fine. Either way doing the locking on the app side for a redis key is a bad idea in general.

Comment: @arrmansa I implemented your suggestions in the server (INCR + modulo) and it is working extremely well, very fluid,, far above my expectations. The application has some routines executed at the startup and, now, I included there an instruction to set the index key at redis to zero. Thank you so much!