# python adding lock to multiprocess pool doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

Possiblely Related Question:
[Trouble using a lock with multiprocessing.Pool: pickling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960296/trouble-using-a-lock-with-multiprocessing-pool-pickling-error)

Problem:
I have a **scraper** running, and created a multiprocess pool to increase the speed. Since I want to pick up if anything happened to break the script, I used pickle to store the value. I added a lock to everywhere involves IO and dictionary update.

Therefore, the first version of code were likes this:

```
def worker():
    pass

total_work = [some list]
remaining_work = [some list]
output_dict = {}

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
while remaining_work: # in case exception, keep trying
    for i in tqdm(p.imap_unordered(worker, remaining_work), total=len(remaining_work)):
        lock.acquire()
        output_dict.update(i)
        with open('cache', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(output_dict, f)
        with open('cache', 'rb') as f:
            current_dict = pickle.load(f)
        remaining_work = [s for s in total_work if s not in current_dict.keys()]
        lock.release()
```

Then I got error `permission denied for opening cache` after some iterations. I think the problem is multiple process perform that `cache` file at the same time, but I just don't understand why, since I already added a lock. Then I read through this post [Trouble using a lock with multiprocessing.Pool: pickling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960296/trouble-using-a-lock-with-multiprocessing-pool-pickling-error), thus replaced my lock as following:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
lock = m.Lock()
```

still get the same error.

Could somebody help me out? Or what is a better way to do this?

feature I want:

- use package `tqdm` as a progressbar showing total progress;
- be able to pick up work from last exception;
- stabilized multiprocess(thread maybe?)

Many thanks!

Comment: Please include the full exception traceback if you're getting an exception - "permission denied for opening cache" looks like a paraphrase, and also we need to know in what line the exception happens in order to be of any help. Also please provide more detail about what `worker` returns.

Comment: In addition, I'm curious why you're writing the pickle and reading it immediately back in to a different variable. That is, when you do `current_dict = pickle.load(f)`, current_dict will be exactly the same as `output_dict`.

Comment: Finally, unless the `worker` function is acquiring and releasing the same `Lock` object that the main process is using, acquiring and releasing that lock in the main process doesn't do anything. Is the worker writing to the output dictionary?

Comment: Input/Output is solely done in the main process. The lock in this case is 100% redundant. Unless the worker is doing something else, the example is for sure not reflecting what the text description implies

Comment: I also think the manipulation of `remaining_work` is an issue here.  The imap_unordered will return every time it finishes processing a single sample and you're updating this list while it's still processing.  It seems like that might cause it to process samples multiple times or have odd behavior.  Should `imap_unordered` be getting `total_work` not remaining?

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks are you suggesting that I need to pass the lock in to worker function as a parameter? and yes, writing and read immedietely looks dump, I need modify that.

Comment: @bivouac0 let the pool handling  `remaining_work` is because this: Suppose we have 8 work to do, after the pool work, we finished 5 and have 3 unfinished due to some exceptions. Then i want the pool to re-try the left 3 work. There is a `while remaining_work` loop outside the `for loop`. I don't know if this is best way to do it, if there is other ways, I will be really appreciate the suggestion

Comment: I would then move your `remaining_work=[...` outside of the `for` loop but still under the while so it can retry but can't interfere with the pool execution.  You may also consider if you're potentially creating an infinite `while` and instead consider allowing a single retry on the `remaining_work` or put a counter in there so your code can't get stuck.